# sockjs-node Cross-Origin Request Blocked warnings after terminating webpack running Vue.js with Ctrl+C

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Working with Django and Vue.js for an application. I'm running the website on https://localhost:8000 and the frontend on port 8080 as a local https grid instance. Before setting up headers, I kept getting CORS errors of this type for every HTTP request:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://u-redwood-testapplicationfrontend.grid.locked.com:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1594916128605. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). [Learn More]

This was fixed by appending the following headers in the webpack config file:

```
headers: {
   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
   "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
},
```

I likewise added https with the key, certificate, and certificate authority.

After this, the errors largely went away. However, whenever I Ctrl+C my development server, I get the above error in increments of 1-2-4-8-16-32-64-128-... seconds like so:

> [WDS] Disconnected!
>
>  
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://u-redwood-testapplicationfrontend.grid.locked.com:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1594916128605. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). [Learn More]
>
>  
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://u-redwood-testapplicationfrontend.grid.locked.com:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1594916128605. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). [Learn More]
>
>  
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://u-redwood-testapplicationfrontend.grid.locked.com:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1594916128605. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). [Learn More]

Is this normal behavior? Is this some kind of Keep-Alive that CORS sends?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For me running `npm run build` / `vue-cli-service build` and then restarting the `serve` process fixes this.

It seemed to happen for me when switching the network I was working from - not totally sure what the exaplanation is though.